# How to increase font size for Edge and Nodes using Diagrams

Tags: python, diagram

I'm using Diagrams as code which uses the Diagrams Python module. I'm trying to increase the font size for Edge labels but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Edge only seems to accept `attr` instead of `graph_attr` so I've tried variations with no luck.

Examples I've tried are:

```
Edge(style="dotted", label="patches", attr="fontsize=20")
Edge(style="dotted", label="patches", attr={"fontsize": "20"})
Edge(style="dotted", label="patches", fontsize="20")

Internet(label="Internet", attr="fontsize=20")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but I was able to get the following variations working.

```
Edge(color="black", label="texthere", fontsize="20")

font = "20"
Edge(color="black", label="texthere", fontsize=font)
```

There is also a head and tail label. See the following examples:

```
Edge(color="red", headlabel="port info", labelfontsize="20")
```